# Split up a massive WSDL file

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, suds, netsuite

I am working on interacting with the Netsuite Web Services layer with Python. Using suds to parse the WSDL takes close to two minutes. I was able to write a caching layer using redis that solves a bit of the loading headaches once the client has been parsed, but it still takes a ton of time the first time around.

```
>>> # Takes several minutes to load
>>> client = suds.Client(huge_four_mb_wsdl_file)
```

Since I only use a small subset of the services, is there a way to pull only those services from the WSDL and put them into my own smaller WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [v2013_2 version of the wsdl](https://webservices.na1.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2013_2_0/netsuite.wsdl) source you'll see that it's actually importing 38 other xsd files.

You can speed up your proccess by:

- Creating a local wsdl that only imports some of the xsd files. (saves download/parse time)
- Serialising a ready client using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) and loading it on boot (saves parse time)

Also make sure you only have to create the client once in your application lifetime.